# PHP MYSQL array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, inner-join

I'm running the following code in PHP to generate the random list of movies from the database but since value of genere is an array it is just capturing the first value of the array.

How can I modify the query so that I can get all the values of genere in comma separated line.

```
      $q = "SELECT *
            FROM
              title
              INNER JOIN title_genere ON (title.id = title_genere.id_title)
              INNER JOIN genere ON (title_genere.id_genere = genere.id)
            ORDER BY RAND()  
            LIMIT 8";

$result = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    $poster = $row['poster'];
    $poster = str_replace("./", "lib/", $poster);
    $genere = $row['genere'];

    echo "<div id='a'>";
    echo "<div id='b'>".$title.'</div>';
    echo "<div id='c'>".$year.'</div>';
    echo "<div id='d'><a href='select.php?movieid=$id'><img src='$poster' alt='' border='1' align='center' width='214' height='314' /></a></div>";
    echo "<div id='e'>".$genere.'</div>';
    echo "</div>";
    //var_dump($genere);
}
```

Comment: Look into using mysql's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$q = "SELECT 
          *, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(title_genere AS BINARY) SEPARATOR ',') AS generes
      FROM
          title
          INNER JOIN title_genere ON (title.id = title_genere.id_title)
          INNER JOIN genere ON (title_genere.id_genere = genere.id)
      ORDER BY RAND()  
      GROUP BY title.id
      LIMIT 8";
```

This should select a comma-separated list on generes into the key `generes`. For more information see the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Why he should use `CAST … AS BINARY`?

Comment: @kuboslav I took the code from one of my projects and I have found it on the internet a long time ago. Would `GROUP_CONCAT(title_genere SEPARATOR ',') AS generes` be correct?

Comment: I suppose it would be better – `CAST` is unnecessary.

Comment: This works fine if I dont use "ORDER BY RAND()" but as soon as I add this line in SQL query it gives me error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GROUP_CONCAT/GROUP BY, it causes overhead.

First, select your 8 random titles (from the `titles` table only) into an associative array indexed by title id. Let's name it $idx.

Next, prepare the id list, say, as $ids variable.

Then, run the query

```
SELECT 
 title_genere.id_title
 , genre.genre
FROM
 title_genre
 INNER JOIN genre ON title_genere.id_genere = genere.id
WHERE 
 title_genere.id_title IN ($ids)
ORDER BY
 genre
```

and harvest `genre` values in lists in `$idx`:

```
$idx[$row['id_title']]['genres'][] = $row['genre']
```

Finally, generate HTML from $idx.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out. I use below code to generate what I want. Thanks everyone for the help

```
SELECT 
      title.id,
      title.title,
      GROUP_CONCAT(genere SEPARATOR ' | ') AS genere,
      title.`year`,
      title.poster
    FROM
      title
      INNER JOIN title_genere ON (title.id = title_genere.id_title)
      INNER JOIN genere ON (title_genere.id_genere = genere.id)
    GROUP BY
      title.id,
      title.title,
      title.`year`,
      title.poster
    ORDER BY
      RAND()
    LIMIT 8
```